# How to convert between Linq expressions with different return types?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I'm having a headache trying to convert the following linq expression.

```
    Expression<Func<T, object>>
```

to the following linq expression...

```
    Expression<Func<T, U>>
```

In the example above the object is always of type `U`.

I know how easy it could to convert/cast between parameter types but I'm not too sure how to cast between return types.

Comment: This question could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171737/conversion-of-linq-expressions-from-business-to-domain-types

Comment: Seems to be related but it's not. I need to cast the return type not the parameter. Cast the parameter of the expression is fairly straight-forward

Comment: Could you give some more details about the code? Are the two expression return type of two methods in a class?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570942/translating-expression-tree-from-a-type-to-another-type-with-complex-mappings/10643755#10643755

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to create a new expression by:

1. Using [`Expression.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx) over the source expression's body to create the result's body.
2. Using this body and reusing the parameters of the source expression to create the transformed lambda expression with [`Expression.Lambda`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340145.aspx).

Try this:

```
Expression<Func<T, object>> source = ...

var resultBody = Expression.Convert(source.Body, typeof(U));    
var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, U>>(resultBody, source.Parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

My case was converting interface input type to the concrete type for my MongoDB generic repository.

I was converting from

```
Expression<Func<TIModel, bool>> iFilter
```

to

```
Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> filter
```

I just inspired from Ani's answer and converted like:

```
var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(iFilter.Body, iFilter.Parameters);
```