# Why would I want to use an ExpressionVisitor?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, expressionvisitor

I know from the MSDN's article about [How to: Modify Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654266.aspx) what an `ExpressionVisitor` is supposed to do. It should modify expressions.

Their example is however pretty unrealistic so I was wondering why would I need it? Could you name some real-world cases where it would make sense to modify an expression tree? Or, why does it have to be modified at all? From what to what?

It has also many overloads for visiting all kinds of expressions. How do I know when I should use any of them and what should they return? I saw people using `VisitParameter` and returning `base.VisitParameter(node)` the other on the other hand were returning `Expression.Parameter(..)`.

Comment: If you want to modify a tree structure, a visitor is a pretty standard technique to achieve that, especially for immutable trees. This provides a base class for such visitors. You only override the methods for the node types you need to alter and return the new nodes. The visitor as a whole incrementally builds a new tree.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski this is what I already found out (ok, without the node types, this I didn't know) I'm rather interested in what I could have before and what would come out. What kind of expression trees require modifications from what to what? This is the missing link.

Comment: Heh, the answer is *whatever you need to get done*. Expression trees don't *require* modifications, *you* may need to modify them for some reason. See [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for a real example (AsExpandable rewrites expressions).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I'm sorry but this link does not provide any help. They're not using the _real_ `ExpressionVisitor` from MS but their own implementation, who knows what they were thinking ;-]

Comment: The real one was `internal` back in the day, I remember having copy/pasted a decompiled version so I could use it. MS finally decided to make it public though. I suppose LINQKit has a custom version for the same reason, and this lets them support older framework versions.

Comment: Well, at some point I had to translate LINQ queries from a domain object to an entity generated from the framework and Expression Vistors came in handy. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570942/translating-expression-tree-from-a-type-to-another-type-with-complex-mappings/10643755#10643755

Comment: @MaksimSimkin I'm happy to see that someone else finds this question interesting too and even worth a bounty :) Expression threes have been a mystery for me for a long time. They seem to be quite powerful but I never coudn't figure out how to use them properly. The documentation explains a few things but nothing really useful that you could need for every-day development.

Comment: @t3chb0t the MSDN documentation? As well as that, there's the very informative https://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=dlr&DownloadId=246540 which has both some high-level and low-level detail and while some things it describes were never implemented, it gives a different perspective.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Could you name some real-world cases where it would make sense to modify an expression tree?

Strictly speaking, we never modify an expression tree, as they are immutable (as seen from the outside, at least, there's no promise that it doesn't internally memoise values or otherwise have mutable private state). It's precisely because they are immutable and hence we can't just change a node that the visitor pattern makes a lot of sense if we want to create a new expression tree that is based on the one we have but different in some particular way (the closest thing we have to modifying an immutable object).

We can find a few within Linq itself.

In many ways the simplest Linq provider is the linq-to-objects provider that works on enumerable objects in memory.

When it receives enumerables directly as `IEnumerable<T>` objects it's pretty straight-forward in that most programmers could write an unoptimised version of most of the methods pretty quickly. E.g. `Where` is just:

```
foreach (T item in source)
  if (pred(item))
    yield return item;
```

And so on. But what about `EnumerableQueryable` implementing the `IQueryable<T>` versions? Since the `EnumerableQueryable` wraps an `IEnumerable<T>` we could do the desired operation on the one or more enumerable objects involved, but we have an expression describing that operation in terms of `IQueryable<T>` and other expressions for selectors, predicates, etc, where what we need is a description of that operation in terms of `IEnumerable<T>` and delegates for selectors, predicates, etc.

[`System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq.Queryable/src/System/Linq/EnumerableRewriter.cs) is an implementation of `ExpressionVisitor` does exactly such a re-write, and the result can then simply be compiled and executed.

Within `System.Linq.Expressions` itself there are a few implementations of `ExpressionVisitor` for different purposes. One example is that the interpreter form of compilation can't handle hoisted variables in quoted expressions directly, so it uses a visitor to rewrite it into working on indices into a a dictionary.

As well as producing another expression, an `ExpressionVisitor` can produce another result. Again `System.Linq.Expressions` has internal examples itself, with debug strings and `ToString()` for many expression types working by visiting the expression in question.

This can (though it doesn't have to be) be the approach used by a database-querying linq provider to turn an expression into a SQL query.

> How do I know when I should use any of them and what should they return?

The default implementation of these methods will:

1. If the expression can have no child expressions (e.g. the result of `Expression.Constant()`) then it will return the node back again.
2. Otherwise visit all the child expressions, and then call `Update` on the expression in question, passing the results back. `Update` in turn will either return a new node of the same type with the new children, or return the same node back again if the children weren't changed.

As such, if you don't know you need to explicitly operate on a node for whatever your purposes are, then you probably don't need to change it. It also means that `Update` is a convenient way to get a new version of a node for a partial change. But just what "whatever your purposes are" means of course depends on the use case. The most common cases are probably go to one extreme or the other, with either just one or two expression types needing an override, or all or nearly all needing it.

(One caveat is if you are examining the children of those nodes that have children in a `ReadOnlyCollection` such as `BlockExpression` for both its steps and variables or `TryExpression` for its catch-blocks, and you will only sometimes change those children then if you haven't changed you are best to check for this yourself as a flaw [recently fixed, but not in any released version yet] means that if you pass the same children to `Update` in a different collection to the original `ReadOnlyCollection` then a new expression is created needlessly which has effects further up the tree. This is normally harmless, but it wastes time and memory).

Answer (score 22):

There was a issue where on the database we had fields which contained 0 or 1 (numeric), and we wanted to use bools on the application.

The solution was to create a "Flag" object, which contained the 0 or 1 and had a conversion to bool. We used it like a bool through all the application, but when we used it in a .Where() clause the EntityFramework complained that it is unable to call the conversion method.

So we used a expression visitor to change all property accesses like .Where(x => x.Property) to .Where(x => x.Property.Value == 1) just before sending the tree to EF.

Comment: This is really a great real-life example.

Answer (score 9):

The [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) enables the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) for `Expression`'s.

Conceptually, the problem is that when you navigate an `Expression` tree, all you know is that any given node is an `Expression`, but you don't know specifically what kind of `Expression`.  This pattern allows you to know what kind of `Expression` you're working with and specify type-specific handling for different kinds.

When you have an `Expression`, you can just call `.Modify`.  The `Expression` knows its own type, so it'll call back the appropriate `override`.

Looking at the [MSDN example you linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654266.aspx):

```
public class AndAlsoModifier : ExpressionVisitor  
{  
    public Expression Modify(Expression expression)  
    {  
        return Visit(expression);  
    }  

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)  
    {  
        if (b.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso)  
        {  
            Expression left = this.Visit(b.Left);  
            Expression right = this.Visit(b.Right);  

            // Make this binary expression an OrElse operation instead of an AndAlso operation.  
            return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.OrElse, left, right, b.IsLiftedToNull, b.Method);  
        }  

        return base.VisitBinary(b);  
    }  
}
```

In this example, if the `Expression` happens to be a `BinaryExpression`, it'll call back `VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)` given in the example.  Now, you can deal with that `BinaryExpression` knowing that it's a `BinaryExpression`.  You could also specify other `override` methods that handle other kinds of `Expression`'s.

It's worth noting that, since this is an overloaded resolution trick, visited `Expression`'s will call back the best-fitting method.  So, if there're different kinds of `BinaryExpression`'s, then you could write an `override` for one specific subtype; if another subtype calls back, it'll just use the default `BinaryExpression` handling.

In short, this pattern allows you to navigate an `Expression` tree knowing what kind of `Expression`'s you're working with.

Comment: Oh, I didn't associate it with the visitor pattern at all. I like your explanation and with the other example I start to get the idea of it, I hope. I actually need to know the expression tree that I want to manipulate so that I know at which node(s) I should _stop_, take a look at and modify if necessary the way I need it to work/behave.

Comment: @t3chb0t Sounds like you've found the right tool, then!  There're other ways you can get get this benefit (which is often described as [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C.23)), but the visitor pattern's a popular way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Specific real world example I have just encountered occurred when shifting to EF Core and migrating from Sql Server (MS Specific) to SqlLite (platform independent).

The existing business logic revolved around a middle tier/ service layer interface that assumed Full Text Search (FTS) happened auto-magically in the background which it does with SQL Server. Search related queries were passed into this tier via Expressions and FTS against an Sql Server store required no additional FTS specific entities.

I didn't want to change any of this but with SqlLite you have to target a specific virtual table for a Full Text Search which would in turn have meant changing all the middle tier calls to re-target the FTS tables/entities and then  joining them to the business entity tables to get a similar result set.

But by sub-classing ExpressionVisitor I was able to intercept the calls in the DAL layer and simply rewrite the incoming expression (or more precisely some of the BinaryExpressions within the overall search expression) to specifically handle SqlLites FTS requirements.

This meant that specialization of the datalayer to the data store happened within a single class that was called from a single place within a repository base class. No other aspects of the application needed to be altered in order to support FTS via EFCore and any SqlLite FTS related entities could be contained in a single pluggable assembly.

So ExpressionVisitor is really very useful, especially when combined with the whole notion of being able to pass around expression trees as data via various forms of IPC.