# C# Linq Expression - How to get the instance of an expression

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, linq-expressions

Is there any way to get the used instance from a linq expression as a reference or something else?

At the moment I have the following to declare my expression:

```cs
var testClass = new ClassToTest();
otherClass.RunTest(() => testClass.NumberOfCars);
```

Now I want to get the used instance object from the expression. So that I could later get another property dynamically for example. I know that I can just pass more parameters to the function itself to use them but I wonder if this is also possible by expression.

Update

```cs
public class ClassToTest
{
    public int NumberOfCars;
    public int NumberOfChildren;

    public ClassToTest()
    {
        NumberOfCars = 1;
        NumberOfChildren = 2;
    }
}

public class TestingClass<TResult>
{
    public bool RunTest(Expression<Func<TResult>> expression)
    {
        // var numberOfCars = get info with the help of the expression and reflection 
        // var instance = get used instance in expression
        if (instance.NumberOfChildren > 2 && numberOfCars == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

var otherClass = new TestingClass<int>();
```

It is just a basic example to understand my problem. The example could be better solved to pass both values as a parameter and check them but I wondered if this is possible to archive so.

Comment: What if you don´t even have any instance? E.g. `(RunTest(() => 3)`. This question does not make much sense, as it assumes an expression allways represents an instance-method-call. But it could be **any** delegate. If you want to have such an expression, your delegate surely should also expect that instance as parameter.

Comment: Anyway I can´t see where you use that expression. Why do you think you even need any?

Answer (score 1):

An `Expression` is a tree of what is compiled by the C# compiler. You should use an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432852/why-would-i-want-to-use-an-expressionvisitor) to extract information of `Expression`

Your basic example is not that trivial. You declare a variable outside the expression and use it inside. It is a called a closure. You also use field instead of property which will result in different expression.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassToTest testClass = new ClassToTest();
        new TestingClass<Int32>().RunTest(() => testClass.NumberOfCars);
    }
}
```

Will be compiled as

```
internal class Program
{
  [CompilerGenerated]
  private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
  {
    public ClassToTest testClass;
  }

  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.testClass = new ClassToTest();
    new TestingClass<int>().RunTest(
      Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(
        Expression.Field(
          Expression.Field(
            Expression.Constant(<>c__DisplayClass0_, typeof(<>c__DisplayClass0_0)),
            "testClass", //FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle((RuntimeFieldHandle)/*OpCode not supported: LdMemberToken*/)),
          "NumberOfCars", //FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle((RuntimeFieldHandle)/*OpCode not supported: LdMemberToken*/)), 
         Array.Empty<ParameterExpression>()));
  }
}
```

To get the instance object without using an expression visitor you can do :

```
public bool RunTest(Expression<Func<TResult>> expression)
{
    // NumberOfCars
    var e1 = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    // testClass
    var e2 = (MemberExpression)e1.Expression;
    // closureObject 
    var e3 = (ConstantExpression)e2.Expression; 

    var closureObject = e3.Value;
    var testClassObject = ((FieldInfo)e2.Member).GetValue(closureObject);
    var numberOfCars = ((FieldInfo)e1.Member).GetValue(testClassObject);
 }
```

But you should never manipulate an expression tree like this. Always use an `ExpressionVisitor` and always understand what you are visiting.

The following visitor is an example that will work for your specific scenario.

```
public class XVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public static Object XVisit(Expression e)
    {
        XVisitor visitor = new XVisitor();
        visitor.Visit(e);

        return visitor._instance;
    }

    private Object _instance;

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression.Type.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() != null)
        {
            Object closureInstance = ((ConstantExpression)node.Expression).Value;
            this._instance = ((FieldInfo)node.Member).GetValue(closureInstance);
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

With `ExpressionVisitor` you can do almost everything you want with expression but you need a good understanding on how things works within the C# compiler.