# C# Expression Tree AndAlso for Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I get an error when trying to combine two expressions with `AndAlso`.

**Step 1**: building expression for EF object with expression tree:

```
public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression()
{
    var expressionParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    var expressionField = Expression.PropertyOrField(expressionParameter, field);
    var expressionConstraint = Expression.Constant(value);

    BinaryExpression expression = Expression.Equal(expressionField, expressionConstraint);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, expressionParameter);
}
```

If I'm calling `.ToExpression();` and running this for one expression, this code works fine with EF, it produces expression:

```
{ p => (p.MyField1 == "X") }
```

But when I'm trying to do

**Step 2**: combine two expressions with `AndAlso`:

```
public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression()
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> leftExpression = left.ToExpression();
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> rightExpression = right.ToExpression();

    BinaryExpression andExpression = Expression.AndAlso(leftExpression.Body, rightExpression.Body);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(andExpression, leftExpression.Parameters.Single());
}
```

This produces an expression:

```
{ p => ((p.MyField1 == "X") AndAlso (p.MyField2 == "Y")) }
```

It seems fine to me, but when trying to call it with `.Where(expression)` I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'p' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Any idea why separate expressions work but combined with `AndAlso` don't?

Comment: Have you considered using PredicateBuilder / LinqKit instead of doing this manually by yourself?

Comment: No, I will take a look, but still curious why this doesn't work

Comment: I imagine it fails because `AndAlso` is the VB.NET short-circuiting version of VB.NET's `And` combinator (which famously is _not_ short-circuiting) - whereas SQL (which is what I assume you're using this for?) does not define sequence-order for expressions so it makes no sense to support `AndAlso` instead of just `And`.

Comment: I have tried to also use `And` instead `AndAlso` but im getting same result for expression: `{p => ((p.MyField1 == "X") And (p.MyField2 == "Y"))}`, and yes this is for SQL

Comment: I'd like to play around with this - where do I put the `ToExpression` method?

Comment: When you combine the expressions, I suspect ef core is not able to take "p" as same parameter reference , rather consider them different, perhaps you could use expressionVisitor to replace parameter https://stackoverflow.com/a/41652669/1398461

Comment: @Dai I have a generic class where T is my EF object, just passing a `field` and `value` for filtering and the result of 'ToExpression()' is passed to `.Where()` in EF call, can provide more complete code if needed

Comment: Lambda expressions cannot be combined this way because they use different `ParameterExpression` instances (the name doesn't matter). `Expression.Invoke` is limited and not always supported, you need `ParameterReplacer`, there are a lot of examples here.

Comment: @Carlos28 what's the point of this? SQL has no `AndAlso` because the order of the operands doesn't matter. The *best* SQL this `AndAlso` can produce is just `AND`. The database will use the actual operand, table schema, indexes *and* data statistics to come up with an execution plan that works on streams of rows. Short-circuiting has no meaning , unless the parser determines a condition is always true and eliminates it, like `AND 1=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing `ParameterReplacer` did the trick, implementation that I have found and used:

```
    internal class ReplaceExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression _oldValue;
    private readonly Expression _newValue;

    public ReplaceExpressionVisitor(Expression oldValue, Expression newValue)
    {
        _oldValue = oldValue;
        _newValue = newValue;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node) => node == _oldValue ? _newValue : base.Visit(node);
}
```

Thank's for your suggestions.

Comment: What SQL did this emit? Was it identical to `AND` perhaps? SQL has no `AndAlso` and in fact, the order doesn't matter when it comes to generating an execution plan. The execution plan will pick indexes and filtering strategies that work on streams of data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, EF Core translates `Expression.AndAlso` (and only this binary expression) into logical AND. `Expression.And` is bitwise operator and has different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Expression.Lambda` calls probably need to start with a call to `Expression.Invoke` like this:

```cs
var expr = Expression.Invoke(expression, expressionParameter);
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expr, expressionParameter);
```